# Jenkins Build with Parameters through REST API returns strange header and doesn't build

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, curl

I'm trying to use the Jenkins REST API through curl and when I manually use the curl command I get a build, but when I run the same command through a script I get a strange header and footer, with the html basically being a Jenkins search bar and logo and the standard footer.

The output looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class=""><head resURL="/static/ba2a3c09" data-rooturl="" data-resurl="/static/ba2a3c09" data-imagesurl="/static/ba2a3c09/images">



    <title>Jenkins [Jenkins]</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ba2a3c09/jsbundles/base-styles-v2.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ba2a3c09/css/color.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/ba2a3c09/css/responsive-grid.css" type="text/css"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/ba2a3c09/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"><link color="black"... Oops!</span></h1><div id="error-description"><h2 style="text-align: center">A problem occurred while processing the request.</h2><p style="text-align: center">Logging ID= ... </div></div></div><footer class="page-footer"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="page-footer__flex-row"><div class="page-footer__footer-id-placeholder" id="footer"></div><div class="page-footer__timestamp hidden-xs hidden-sm"><span class="page-footer__generated">
              Page generated:
```

I redacted a lot of it as I think most of it is useless info. With verbose output I can see that authentication through the API token doesn't fail, so I'm pretty stumped. Has anyone had a similar situation?

Comment: So it's a problem with your script. So add the script you tried to use.

Comment: Please provide your curl command, as well as your script.

Comment: Also share the rest api endpoint. The html response means you are occasioning an error in jenkins. Also check the log /var/logs/jenkins/jenkins.log